# Mysql PREPARE statement is taking much times at the time of record insertion

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, rdbms

I am using `PREPARE` statement in store procedure but it is taking much time at the time of records insertion. Please suggest me the replacement for `PREPARE` statement.

```
SET @COUNT = 0;
SET @countQuery = CONCAT("select count(ufl.id) INTO @COUNT from user_friend_list as ufl where ufl.user_id = ",@USERREGID," AND ufl.friend_user_id = ",FID);
  PREPARE STMTC FROM @countQuery; 
 EXECUTE STMTC; 


IF @COUNT = 0 THEN
INSERT INTO user_friend_list(user_id, friend_user_id) VALUES(@USERREGID,FID),(FID,@USERREGID);
    END IF;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMTC;
```

Comment: Define "much times". In numbers preferably.

Comment: You prepared statement seems to only *read* information. Your insertion does not appear to be done by a prepare statement.

Comment: @RandomSeed :  I know about that I am asking replacement of PREPARE statement. I am debugging code and see PREPARE statement is taking much time and I am looking optimization.

Comment: I see. Your phrasing is misleading, perhaps rewrite it with "at time of *creation*". Or is it "at time of *execution*"? In the latter case, have you tried to execute the underlying `SELECT` statement outside of a prepared statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do this

```
IF 0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM user_friend_list 
         WHERE user_id = @USERREGID
           AND friend_user_id = FID) THEN
    INSERT INTO user_friend_list(user_id, friend_user_id) 
    VALUES (@USERREGID,FID), (FID,@USERREGID);
END IF;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba71e/4)** demo